# C++ weak functor with default return value

Tags: c++, templates, functor

With the help of this community, I have the following template methods...

```
// void return
template<typename R, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<R>::value, R>::type,
         typename F, typename T, typename... A>
static std::function<R()> Weak(F func, const std::shared_ptr<T>&& obj, A&&... args)
{
    return std::bind(Wrapper<R>(), std::weak_ptr<T>(obj),
                     std::function<R()>(std::bind(func, obj.get(), args...)));
}

// non void return
template<typename R, R D = R(), typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<R>::value == false, R>::type,
         typename F, typename T, typename... A>
static std::function<R()> Weak(F func, const std::shared_ptr<T>&& obj, A&&... args)
{
    return std::bind(Wrapper<R>(), std::weak_ptr<T>(obj),
                     std::function<R()>(std::bind(func, obj.get(), args...)), D);
}
```

...where Wrapper is a template class that tests the weak pointer and returns the specified default value if it is expired.  Usage examples are...

```
(a) Bind::Weak<void>(func, obj, args...)
(b) Bind::Weak<bool>(func, obj, args...)        // default bool is "false"
(c) Bind::Weak<bool, true>(func, obj, args...)
(b) Bind::Weak<int>(func, obj, args...)         // default int is "0"
(c) Bind::Weak<int, 42>(func, obj, args...)
```

Is it be possible to support the following usage instead?

```
(a) Bind::Weak<void>(func, obj, args...)
(b) Bind::Weak<true>(func, obj, args...)
(c) Bind::Weak<42>(func, obj, args...)
```

[EDIT] The response from Oktalist below gave me the following idea...

```
// weak from shared - void return
template<typename F, typename O, typename... A>
static std::function<void()> Weak(F func, const std::shared_ptr<O>&& obj, A&&... args)
{
    return std::bind(Wrapper<void>(), std::weak_ptr<O>(obj), std::function<void()>(std::bind(func, obj.get(), std::forward<A>(args)...)));
}

// weak from shared - non-void return
template<typename F, typename R = typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<F>::value == false, F>::type, typename O, typename... A>
static std::function<R()> Weak(R&& val, F func, const std::shared_ptr<O>&& obj, A&&... args)
{
    return std::bind(Wrapper<R>(), std::weak_ptr<O>(obj), std::function<R()>(std::bind(func, obj.get(), std::forward<A>(args)...)), val);
}
```

...which gives this usage...

```
(a) Bind::Weak(func, obj, args...)
(b) Bind::Weak(true, func, obj, args...)
(c) Bind::Weak(42, func, obj, args...)
```

Comment: I finally got my version to compile: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02d62687f7de4547

Comment: Careful with your sample inspired by Oktalist, it only allows rvalues for the default return value.  You probably don't want that restriction.

Comment: Pretty much came up with the same thing :)

Comment: Yeah, very similar.  Mine works with functionoids with multiple overloads and _sometimes_ makes less copies of the default return.  I like his idea of the implicit default, though that requires a deducible return type, which isn't possible with functionoids with multiple overloads. :/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, you can deduce the return type of the callable type `F` using [function traits](http://functionalcpp.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/function-traits/).

Remove `typename R` from the template parameter list, move `typename F` to the beginning of the template parameter list, and replace all occurrences of `R` with `typename function_traits<F>::return_type`. We can use a `template using` declaration to help us:

```
template <typename F>
using Ret = typename function_traits<F>::return_type;

template <typename T>
using EnableIfVoid = typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<T>::value, T>::type;
template <typename T>
using EnableIfNotVoid = typename std::enable_if<! std::is_void<T>::value, T>::type;

// void return
template<typename F, typename = EnableIfVoid<Ret<F>>, typename T, typename... A>
static std::function<void()> Weak(F func, const std::shared_ptr<T>& obj, A&&... args)
{
    return std::bind(Wrapper<void>(), std::weak_ptr<T>(obj),
                     std::function<void()>(std::bind(func, obj.get(),
                                                     std::forward<Args>(args)...)));
}

// non void return with explicit default
template<typename F, typename = EnableIfNotVoid<Ret<F>>, typename T, typename... A>
static std::function<Ret<F>()> Weak(Ret<F> d, F func, const std::shared_ptr<T>& obj, A&&... args)
{
    return std::bind(Wrapper<Ret<F>>(), std::weak_ptr<T>(obj),
                     std::function<Ret<F>()>(std::bind(func, obj.get(),
                                                       std::forward<Args>(args)...)), d);
}

// non void return with implicit default
template<typename F, typename = EnableIfNotVoid<Ret<F>>, typename T, typename... A>
static std::function<Ret<F>()> Weak(F func, const std::shared_ptr<T>& obj, A&&... args)
{
    return Weak(Ret<F>(), func, obj, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

I had to make your `D` parameter a function argument instead of a template parameter, otherwise you would've been forced to write `Bind::Weak<decltype(f), 42>(f, obj)`.

```
(a) Bind::Weak(func, obj, args...)
(b) Bind::Weak(true, func, obj, args...)
(c) Bind::Weak(42, func, obj, args...)
```

[I feel you should be able to do this without having to call `bind` twice, but I don't know enough about what you are trying to do.]

Comment: Take a function, a `share_ptr`, a default return value, and some parameters: produce a functionoid.  Functionoid should take no arguments and return the same type as the function.  Functionoid should store a `weak_ptr` to the `shared_ptr`.  When invoked, if the `weak_ptr` is valid, it calls the function with the pointee of the smart pointers, and the given arguments.  If not valid, it returns the default return value.  (This is all assumed, but seems like a safe assumption)

Comment: More than I was looking for, but it gave me an idea on how to proceed.  See edited question above.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of which might help you tackle this problem is to overload your non-void version of Weak for each kind of non-type template argument you might support. In your example this is a bool and an int.

This is not your code as it's simplified but hopefully conveys the idea:

```
// accepts a type. using enable_if you'd do something like this
// to catch all the non-void types that don't have a default value.
template <class R, ...enable_if to only deal with non-void... >
R Get( R r )
{
  return r;
}

// this for if the user wants to put an actual value as a parameter
// to be the default rather than just 'int'
template <int R>
decltype(R) Get( decltype(R) r = R )
{
  return r;
}


// ... and do the previous one for each specific type which can have a default
```

Basically the issue is that specific values like '42' and 'false' won't bind to a 'typename'. So you need specialized templates of the function to accept these values and you can then get the type of that value when you need to using decltype(). This will remove the need for sometimes having one parameter (ie: Get< int >) and other times two (ie: Get< int, 42 > to have the default specified).

Another restriction which seems acceptable for your example but is probably not acceptable in the 'real world' is limitations on the template argument itself. You won't be able to do Weak< foo > where foo is an instance of a class.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent some time on the same problem and came up with this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

template <typename F, typename T>
struct Invoker {
  typedef std::weak_ptr<T> P;

  Invoker(F func, P ptr)
    : func_(func),
      ptr_(ptr) {
  }

  template <typename... Args>
  typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type operator()(Args&&... args) {
    typedef typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type R;
    if (ptr_.lock())
      return func_(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return R();
  }

private:
  F func_;
  P ptr_;
};

template <typename F, typename T, typename... Args>
struct _Bind_helper {
  typedef Invoker<decltype( std::bind(std::declval<F>(), std::declval<Args>()...) ), T> InvokerType;
};

template <typename F, typename T, typename... Args>
typename _Bind_helper<F, T, Args...>::InvokerType
weak_bind(std::weak_ptr<T> ptr, F func, Args&&... args) {
  typedef typename _Bind_helper<F, T, Args...>::InvokerType R;
  return R(std::bind(std::forward<F>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...), ptr);
}
```

There are notable limitations on default result value, but it seems to work most of the time :)